# Arcore fragment crashes on startup

Tags: android, kotlin, arcore

Just started with ARCore. I want to display a simple 3d model on a plane. I am using version 1.10.0 of ARCore. When I start up the app the app crashes with the stacktrace below:

This is my layout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/ar_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        layout="@layout/overlay"
        app:showOverlay="@{showOverlay}" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I use databinding to inflate a layout. I have no Idea what I am doing wrong. It looks like the ArFragment can not be found.

````
2019-07-23 14:05:15.209 12108-12108/com.icapps.arcapps E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.icapps.arcapps, PID: 12108
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.icapps.arcapps/com.icapps.arcapps.activity.products.PlantDetailActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3037)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3172)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1906)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment: calling Fragment constructor caused an exception
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:532)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:57)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$6.instantiate(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2850)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManagerImpl.java:3195)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:134)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:357)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:336)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:545)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:303)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:284)
        at com.icapps.arcapps.activity.products.PlantDetailActivity.onCreate(PlantDetailActivity.kt:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7149)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7140)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3017)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3172)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1906)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
2019-07-23 14:05:15.210 12108-12108/com.icapps.arcapps E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:514)
            ... 33 more
     Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #38 bootstrap method
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.<init>(BaseArFragment.java:97)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment.<init>(ArFragment.java:35)
            ... 36 more
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Bootstrap method returned null
            ... 38 more
2019-07-23 14:05:15.211 12108-12108/com.icapps.arcapps E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.icapps.arcapps, PID: 12108
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.icapps.arcapps/com.icapps.arcapps.activity.products.PlantDetailActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3037)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3172)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1906)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment: calling Fragment constructor caused an exception
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:532)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:57)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$6.instantiate(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2850)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManagerImpl.java:3195)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:134)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:357)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:336)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:545)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:303)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:284)
        at com.icapps.arcapps.activity.products.PlantDetailActivity.onCreate(PlantDetailActivity.kt:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7149)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7140)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3017)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3172)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1906)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
2019-07-23 14:05:15.212 12108-12108/com.icapps.arcapps E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:514)
            ... 33 more
     Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #38 bootstrap method
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.<init>(BaseArFragment.java:97)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment.<init>(ArFragment.java:35)
            ... 36 more
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Bootstrap method returned null
            ... 38 more```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I forgot to add the compile options

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```